# Alternatives to IF ELSE in stored procedure SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am new to stored procedures and still learning, below is what I tried and is working also. But, I have only one change on `ad.Indicator` and I am writing the same query thrice in `IF, ELSE IF`.

Is there a better way to do this? (I am using SQL Server)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE TestingSP 
    @startdate Datetime, 
    @enddate Datetime,
    @source Varchar(10)
AS 
BEGIN 
   IF(@source = 'None')
      SELECT *
      FROM FD.T fd 
      INNER JOIN AD.T ad ON fd.OCD = ad.ACD 
      WHERE fd.SG BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate

   ELSE IF(@source = 'Air')
      SELECT *
      FROM FD.T fd 
      INNER JOIN AD.T ad ON fd.OCD = ad.ACD 
      WHERE fd.SG BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate AND ad.Indicator = 'True'

  ELSE IF(@source = 'Not Air')
      SELECT *
      FROM FD.T fd 
      INNER JOIN AD.T ad ON fd.OCD = ad.ACD 
      WHERE fd.SG BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate AND ad.Indicator = 'False'
END
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do this (although it might possibly result in a worse query plan):

```
Select *
FROM FD.T fd 
INNER JOIN AD.T ad on fd.OCD = ad.ACD 
WHERE fd.SG BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate 
      AND ad.Indicator = CASE 
                              WHEN @source = 'Not Air' THEN 'False'
                              WHEN @source = 'Air' THEN 'True'
                              ELSE ad.Indicator
                         END
```

[Whether that generates a better or worse plan remains to be seen...]

In addition, please note:

- Using SELECT * is not recommended. Use an explicit column list
- A column containing the string values 'True' and "False' would be better as a bit column
- Be careful if your dates have a time portion. If they do, there are several ways to handle this, perhaps the most straightforward way is to cast to Date data type (SQL Server 2008 onwards):

  ```
  WHERE CAST(fd.SG as Date) BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
  ```

But be aware that this might invalidate the use of an appropriate index. (Also assumes that `@startDate` and `@enddate` do not have a time portion)

Comment: +1 they do have a time portion, Could you please suggest what could be done to handle that?

Comment: I believe this will miss the 'None' condition.  Maybe CASE WHEN @source = 'Not Air' THEN 'False' WHEN 'None' THEN ad.Indicator ELSE 'True' END

Comment: You are correct: I missed that (or was it edited?). I'll update. Thanks

Comment: Excellent answer Mitch. Thanks for doing a complete job!